# NextJS - socket.io - CSS _ Flexbox: My flexbox's column fails to create a column of my chat room's users list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I'm working with NextJS and would display a list of my char room's users in column. This list is retrieved after all user have connect, by emiting an event which allow to update my component when a new user enter. The user are stocked in an array of object in my component's State.

I have tried flexbox but I fail. However it seems to me everything is good, also I would add that on codesandbox.io my code works well.

So I have assumed that was because of my `./reset.css`, but it changes nothing if I remove it. I have tried to play with my CSS and JS codes, even by adding explicitly a `<br/>` element, but lol, even the `<br/>` fails to provoke a new line.

So I have assumed, "hey it's the dev mode maybe", I have run `yarn build` to build my next app, then `yarn start` to launch the production mode and awesome! no, that has just fallen.

I have assumed "I'm on, this is the server connection with NextJS that lead to some tricky behavior", I have off the socket.io, turn down the componentDidMount in commentary, then set an array from scratch to appreciate the change: that was even worse.

Okay I have chosen the "help of a peer" option maybe someone here knows what's going on?

interesting hint, it seems it's like my app render the whole component instead of updating the component:

Here my snippet.js:

```
renderRoomUser=(data)=>{         
        return this.state.roomUserStock.map((roomUserItem, index) => {
            console.log("renderRoomUser roomUserItem: ", roomUserItem) 
            return (
                <li
                className={style.room_user_item}
                key={index}> 

                {roomUserItem} 

                </li>
        )})

    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className={style.page}> 

            <div
                className={style.room_user_container} 
            >
                <h2>People</h2>
                <ul className={style.room_user_list}> {this.renderRoomUser()} </ul>
            </div>
```

here my css.snipet:

```
.page{ 
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: rgb(253, 108, 217);  
      /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; */
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "room_user message_area";
    grid-template-columns: 25vw 5fr; 

}




/**** room aera ****/ 

.room_user_container{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-area:room_user;
    background:rgb(228, 104, 104);
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
}

.room_user_container h2{ 

    font-weight:bold;
    justify-self: flex-start;
    margin: 5vh 0;
}

.room_user_container ul{
    background:rgb(96, 255, 130);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: green;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    align-items: center; 
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
} 

.room_user_container ul li{ 
    background:rgb(96, 205, 255);
    height: 100%; // auto rather than 100% for example, would yeild better rendering
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering if it is a problem with the CSS loading flow or something like that

Comment: I have found, the `height:100%` in `room_user_container ul li{...}` leaded to make the li occupates all the height-space, then the other li have to go on a new column. for some reasons maybe in codesandbox.io the `height:100%` failed to provoke these UI effects.